# Porque o fullcalendar não está carregando o css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fullcalendar

Boa tarde

Estou tendo uma certa dificuldade em implementar o fullcalendar.. 
ele aparece tudo certinho, porém o CSS não carrega (eu acho)

Estou fazendo alguma importacao errada? Ou está faltando algo?

Agradeço desde já a todos que tiver seu tempo em me ajudar!

[image: importação css]

[image: importacao js]

[image: o problema]

[image: CONSOLE]

Comment: Verifica no CTRL+U se o arquivo de css do fullcalendar está sendo carregado e coloque o mesmo como último na chamada do css, para não correr o risco de ser sobrescrito. Tem um exemplo de uso dele no link https://fullcalendar.io/ verificando no CTRL+U você consegue saber qual o arquivo de css necessário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deu certo, fiz o que o Roberto Giffone me recomendou. Eram problemas de localização de arquivos!

Obrigado!